# Run two cloud solutions locally and simultaneously

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure

I have two cloud solutions open in two instances of VS 2012. Each one has a Web Role Project. Both run fine, but I am unable to run them both at the same time. If I attempt to bring up one solution while the other is running, my browser just tells me the page is unavailable.

Anyone have any thought as to why this might be? Could one solution be locking the azure emulators for itself?

Comment: Did you try run one without debugger and the other with debugger?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I just did, and it didn't work.

Comment: well, it seems that both are using the same port. You should publish one of then on your local IIS. It should solve your issue.

Comment: One is using 447, the other is 80. I was hoping to avoid publishing to IIS, but perhaps that is my only alternative.